# Adding ActionBar to Android API Level 8 App?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-2.2-froyo

I know there is a lot of fragmented material on how to do do this all over the internet but I am requesting someone to please give me a step by step guide on how to go from the very beginning, adding the library to adding the code into my Android application / project.

I like the look of this one: https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar but I cannot get it to work properly :/ I have a feeling I'm missing something.

My Application is for Android version 2.2.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I wrote ActionBarSherlock which is an extension of the compatibility library designed to provide a single action bar API which works both with a native implementation on pre-3.0 devices as well as with the native ActionBar on post-3.0. This will allow you to write apps which work as low as Android 1.6 and up through Android 4.0+ without having to worry about shuffling between implementations. The library takes care of applying your API calls and theme across the Honeycomb divide.

You can find more information on http://actionbarsherlock.com such as sample applications and documentation.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, thank you for getting back to me Jake. I did have a look at your ActionBar about 20 minutes ago and i liked the idea that it was all the same as the Google / very similar to how you install the Google Action Bar. 

The only issue is, i am VERY new to Android development and understand a lot of concepts but really cannot clearly understand how the action bar is installed and implemented in code. 

I spent a long time on your site looking for a guide of how to install it and i guess i missed it, please can you guide me to a more detailed location? Sorry to seem so "noobish". 

Thank you.

Comment: It's implemented as a library project which does require a bit of setup as we cannot yet distribute it as a simple `.jar`. You basically need to download a release, create a new project in eclipse, choose 'import existing project', and then select the 'library' folder form the download. You can then add it to your project by right clicking, selecting 'Properties', going to the 'Android' tab, and clicking 'Add' at the bottom. Give it a try (and do some Googling about library projects) and come to the forum if you're still having problems: http://abs.io/forum

Comment: @JakeWharton great work with ABS - looking to implement it soon.

Comment: Not able to import library projet from 'ActionBar sherlock' giving me error  "No projects are found to import"

Answer (score 5):

**The ActionBar is in the Support Library now!**

Find the official documentation [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

And a video introduction about how to work with it [here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc)