# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Android Compatability Issue in 2.2

Tags: java, android, eclipse

For making my app compatible down to API 2.2, I added Android compatibility library `appcompat_v7` & changed the necessary things according.

The app is running fine in the newer versions but crashes in version 2.2.

You can see my **logcat** output

```
07-16 14:49:59.551: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: dead code 0x005e-0061 in Lcom/example/indianconstitution/MainActivity;.displayView (I)V
07-16 14:49:59.870: I/dalvikvm(369): Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getActivityLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
07-16 14:49:59.870: W/dalvikvm(369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 325: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getActivityLogo (Landroid/content/ComponentName;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-16 14:49:59.870: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x008b
07-16 14:49:59.880: I/dalvikvm(369): Could not find method android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo.loadLogo, referenced from method android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarView.<init>
07-16 14:49:59.880: W/dalvikvm(369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 321: Landroid/content/pm/ApplicationInfo;.loadLogo (Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
07-16 14:49:59.880: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0099
07-16 14:49:59.890: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: dead code 0x008e-0092 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
07-16 14:49:59.890: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: dead code 0x009c-00a0 in Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ActionBarView;.<init> (Landroid/content/Context;Landroid/util/AttributeSet;)V
07-16 14:50:00.170: I/dalvikvm(369): Could not find method com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu, referenced from method com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity$1.onDrawerClosed
07-16 14:50:00.170: W/dalvikvm(369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8573: Lcom/example/indianconstitution/MainActivity;.invalidateOptionsMenu ()V
07-16 14:50:00.170: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002d
07-16 14:50:00.180: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: dead code 0x0030-0030 in Lcom/example/indianconstitution/MainActivity$1;.onDrawerClosed (Landroid/view/View;)V
07-16 14:50:00.180: I/dalvikvm(369): Could not find method com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity.invalidateOptionsMenu, referenced from method com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity$1.onDrawerOpened
07-16 14:50:00.180: W/dalvikvm(369): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 8573: Lcom/example/indianconstitution/MainActivity;.invalidateOptionsMenu ()V
07-16 14:50:00.180: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x002d
07-16 14:50:00.180: D/dalvikvm(369): VFY: dead code 0x0030-0030 in Lcom/example/indianconstitution/MainActivity$1;.onDrawerOpened (Landroid/view/View;)V
07-16 14:50:00.200: D/AndroidRuntime(369): Shutting down VM
07-16 14:50:00.200: W/dalvikvm(369): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.example.indianconstitution.PhotoFragment
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:180)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.example.indianconstitution.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:135)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-16 14:50:00.220: E/AndroidRuntime(369):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried all answers  provided in these questions but no help:

- [Android java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870995/android-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror)
- [Android error - Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v4.util.SparseArrayCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16641739/android-error-caused-by-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v4-ut)
- [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20900832/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-appcompat-rstyleable)

I tried adding `android-support-v4.jar` also but it was conflicting with the appcompat, so I removed v4 jar.

What should I do now ? Any Idea?

**EDIT:** This is how I call PhotoFragment class by using `displayView(7)` at the last in `onCreate`

```
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0:
        fragment = new IntroductionFragment();
        break;
    case 1:
        fragment = new PrefaceFragment();
        break;
    case 2:
        fragment = new PreambleFragment();
        break;
    case 3:
        fragment = new ContentsFragment();
        break;

    case 4:
        fragment = new SchedulesFragment();
        break;
    case 5:
        fragment = new AppendixFragment();
        break;
    case 6:
        fragment = new AmendmentFragment();
        break;
    case 7:
        fragment = new PhotoFragment();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

Comment: Post here the code where you are calling the PhotoFragment

Comment: Ok, See my edit, I have posted what you have said, I have not displayed the whole code of MainActivity which manages NavigationDrawer

Comment: I have not included v4 library, do I have to use It?

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/21898031/1785412

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getFragmentManager was only added in API11 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()) You should change the code to use getSupportFragmentManager(). You can find more information about the api of android-support-v4.jar here(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html).

You need to use android-support-v4.jar to support fragments in android 2.2